ComposedChart React
<React.Fragment>

        <Stack spacing="1-x">

          <div id="benchmark-filter">

            <BenchmarkFilter

              isSettinsPage={false}

              filterName={'activeFilter'}

              isDefault={false}

              defaultSelectNode={defaultSelectNode}

            />

            <div className="flexdisplay">

              <div className="yaxis">

                <span className="yaxislabel">------</span>

              </div>

              <ResponsiveContainer

                width="99%"

                height={420}

                className="marginGraph"

              >

                <ComposedChart height={450} data={-------}>

                  <CartesianGrid

                    vertical={false}

                    horizontal

                    strokeWidth={0.3}

                    strokeDasharray="4 4"

                    stroke="black"

                    style={{ zIndex: 2 }}

                  />

                  <Layer>

                    {-------.map((entry, index) => (

                      <Rectangle

                        key={`rect-${index}`}

                        x={index * 70} // Adjust according to bar size

                        y={0} // Start from the top of the graph

                        width={70} // Set width to match bar size

                        height={420} // Extend to the full height of the graph

                        fill={

                          index % 2 === 0

                            ? 'rgba(227, 229, 233, 0.28)'

                            : 'rgba(200, 200, 255, 0.28)'

                        }

                        style={{ zIndex: 0 }} // Make sure the rectangles are at the back

                      />

                    ))}

                  </Layer>


{/* {-------.map((entry, index) => (

                    // CHANGED: Add logic to alternate background with left margin of 20px

                    <Rectangle

                      key={`rect-${index}`}

                      // CHANGED: Alternate left margin of 20px

                      x={index * 70 + (index % 2 === 0 ? 20 : 0)}

                      y={0} // Start from top

                      width={70} // Same width as your bars

                      // CHANGED: Set height to match graph height

                      height={420} // Extend to the height of the graph

                      // CHANGED: Alternate background colors based on index

                      fill={

                        index % 2 === 0 ? 'red' : 'yellow'

                        // ? 'rgba(227, 229, 233, 0.28)'

                        // : 'rgba(200, 200, 255, 0.28)'

                      }

                      style={{ zIndex: 70 }}

                    />

                  ))} */}

                  {/* <Bar

                    dataKey="--"

                    barSize={70}

                    fill="red"

                    style={{ zIndex: 8 }}

                    // stroke={'rgba(227, 229, 233, 0.28)'}

                    // strokeWidth={20}

                  /> */}

                  <Bar

                    dataKey="--"

                    barSize={60}

                    fill="#D2E2FF"

                    style={{ zIndex: 1 }}

                    // stroke={'rgba(227, 229, 233, 0.28)'}

                    // strokeWidth={20}

                  />

                  {/* <Bar

                    dataKey="--"

                    barSize={70}

                    fill="rgba(227, 229, 233, 0.28)"

                    style={{ zIndex: 70 }}

                  /> */}

                  <Line

                    type="monotone"

                    dataKey="avgFH"

                    stroke="#FF008E"

                    dot={<CustomDotWithLine barWidth={60} />}

                    style={{ zIndex: 2 }}

                  />

                  <XAxis dataKey="-----" />

                  <YAxis dataKey="--" />

                  <Legend

                    align="left"

                    payload={customLegendPayload}

                    content={(props: any) => (

                      <div

                        style={{

                          display: 'flex',

                          alignItems: 'center',

                        }}

                      >

                        {props.payload.map((entry: any) => (

                          <div

                            key={entry.id}

                            style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}

                          >

                            {entry.id === 'bar' ? (

                              <CustomLegendIconBar />

                            ) : (

                              <CustomLegendIcon />

                            )}

                            <span style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>

                              {entry.value}

                            </span>

                          </div>

                        ))}

                      </div>

                    )}

                    wrapperStyle={{

                      marginTop: '50px !important',

                      left: '50px',

                      position: 'absolute', // Position legend at the bottom

                      bottom: '-25px', // Place at the bottom of the container

                      right: '0px',

                      width: '100%',

                      height: '0px',

                    }}

                  />

                </ComposedChart>

              </ResponsiveContainer>

In this code I was trying to set background patch which is there for alternate bars, tried all these approaches (comments added)
Can it be done using the same component?
Tries stroke method also but that can't make it till top of the graph so ...?
Thanks in advance.
Expecting a background patch section behind every alternate bar.
